# Is it undefined behavior to access an array out of bounds if I know what data is at the accessed adress?

Tags: c++, stack, undefined-behavior

Imagine the following definition.

```cpp
struct X {
    double a[8] {0.0};
    double b[8] {0.0};
}

int main() {
    X x;
    x.a[10] = 1.0;
}
```

Is the behavior of the program undefined when I access `x.a[10]`?

Comment: Note that the term _undefined behavior_ (UB) is used by the C++ standard. If, according to C++ standard, there is UB, the behavior of the program may be well defined by the implementation at the machine code level (which may be your case).

Comment: Yes, it is undefined behaviour, because the standard says so.    A particular implementation (compiler) may elect to do something in particular, and even do so reliably (until you upgrade your compiler, when it may start doing something else because the standard doesn't prevent that either), but that doesn't have any impact on what is undefined according to the standard.

Comment: How do you **know** what data is at the accessed address? Hint: at best you're guessing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is undefined behavior, but not only because the compiler may alter the memory layout of `X`.

It is undefined behavior because the standard says so. As a result the compiler can do *whatever* with this code: the compiler can drop the assignment completely, can assign `1.0` to *all* the 16 elements, can change what *previous* code is doing, can crash the program, format your hard drive, etc.

---

A more realistic, classical example: the following function

```
const int table[4] = {2, 4, 6, 8};

bool exists_in_table(int v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (table[i] == v) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

*always* return `true`, at least in modern gcc with `-O3` (https://godbolt.org/z/f9cbWMYzM)

Comment: Or [print puppies, puppies, puppies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56979248/why-does-this-simple-program-result-in-puppies-puppies-puppies-to-the-console) but some joykill deleted the question.

Comment: @Quimby page not found and I would really like to see how to print puppies, puppies, puppies :(

Comment: @mch Yep, it is deleted, you need 10k rep to see it, [here's a screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/A817xG7).

Comment: @Quimby I suppose its a poor joke. No compiler I tried does what OP claims there

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yea, likely, but still could have been kept around...

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It's undefined behavior. Because the compiler could insert some padding between `a` and `b`. Il could also insert some padding after `b`.
The only thing you can be sure of is that no padding will be put before `a`.

An interesting and very detailed description is provided in [The Lost Art of Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/).

**EDIT**: Petr answer is more precise than mine: "It is undefined behavior because the standard says so." Anyway, sometimes you feel like "Well the standard says so, but it will always work in practice". So it may be useful to know what could happen in real case scenarios. It's unlikely (but possible) that an out of bound access will format your hard drive, and it's much more likely that two structure elements will not be contiguous in memory.

Comment: I've added a (classical) example to my answer that shows that thinking "how it will work in practice" fails even in rather simple situations.

Answer (score 4):

Your false premise is that out of bounds access would be defined, then of course it is ... not undefined. But it is not. You cannot know what data is at the accessed adress. Already the notion of some data being accessed at some adress is not right for the expression `x.a[10]`.

You assume that the two arrays are stored in adjacent memory directly next to each other and  that pointer arithmetics works also beyond the bounds of an array. The first is not true in general and the second is false always.

Pointer arithmetics is only defined within the bounds of an array.

Your code has undefined behavior.

---

Note that your code is not instructions for your CPU. Your code is an abstract description of what the program should do. And `x.a[10]` simply has no meaning in the language. It is not defined. The compiler is not mandated to translate it to anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

It is according to the "undefined behavior sanitizer" built into g++/clang++

```
runtime error: index 10 out of bounds for type 'double [8]'
```

i.e. the out of bounds access you're already worried about, is indeed UB. It's very very risky doing assumptions on memory layout and usually (even when you know what you're doing) the resulting code is not portable.

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f99e987eb684ea8)

Notice in the demo, invocation of the checker happened with `-fsanitize=undefined`. We have great tools, let's use them.

Also notice that if you enable the memory checker, i.e. `-fsanitize=address`, no warning is emitted. That is to say, "just because it doesn't cause runtime memory problems it doesn't mean it's not UB".